# How can I pass a just object instance to a thread in java, so that even if the instance value gets updated should not effect the thread using it

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing an application in which I continuously receive messages. I am storing these messages in an in-memory data structure (say List). I want to write those messages to a file but only after list size reaches some threshold value say 100 messages (perform batch processing on the messages).
One way is I can simply check the list size after every message is received and call a function to write messages to a file if Threshold value is reached. But the problem with this approach is:

1. Calling function may need to wait indefinitely until all the messages are written to the file
2. The incoming messages may be lost in the process or might need to wait for getting stored in the List.

Other way could be to spawn a new thread, which will write messages to a file independently. But when I pass the list (containing messages) to the thread for performing write operation, it gets updated with new messages which are continuously coming in. As a result newly arrived messages also gets written to the file which is not expected.

This should not happen as I am intending the new messages to be written in the next batch.

Can someone suggest me a solution for this requirement, or any improvements in the above approach that can solve my issues.

Comment: you can create sublist(size of batch) and process it or drain it

Comment: 2nd the cloning idea.  as you serialize the clone, you delete every item from the original list that was also in the clone, that way you avoid deleting the messages that came while the clone serialization was taking place.

Comment: you do want to synchronize the process of cloning to make sure no new messages come in while the cloning is taking place to avoid omitting uncommitted messages in the clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that you never pass an *object* around in Java - only ever a *reference* (or a primitive value).

Options:

- Create a copy of the list, and pass a reference to that copy to your new thread
- Use a producer/consumer queue, so your "producing" thread only *ever* adds values to the queue, and your consumer thread only *ever* takes items from the queue to write them to disk. You'll want to think about how large you want the queue to potentially get before it stops accepting more entries, of course.

I'd recommend the latter approach, using the classes in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) package to implement it; particularly [`BlockingQueue<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Blocking Queue does solve the cause. But other solution also could be to clone the object. I am OK, even if the application has to take the responsibility of providing thread safety which is the case with Blocking Queue. My aim is to provide faster execution which I doubt is possible with Blocking Queue.

Comment: Also I want both producing and consuming to be carried out independently. It should not happen that producer of messages has to wait until all the messages are consumed. Producer should keep producing messages and if a certain limit is reached consumer must consume the messages. But while consuming messages, producer must still be able to produce messages if any. What is your take on this ?

Answer (score 5):

I find a cleaner solution is to support auto-batching. i.e. where the size of the batch adjusts with the rate of incoming data.

To do this you can use a BlockingQueue

```
// unbound queue will not block the producer.
final BlockingQueue<T> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();

// to add an element.
queue.add(element);

// to get a batch of data
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(maxElements);
while(writing) {
    T t = queue.take(); // wait for at least one element.
    list.add(t);
    queue.drainTo(list, maxElements-1);
    // process list, e.g. write to a file.
    list.clear();
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that if the producer is very slow, you won't get elements held unreasonably long, but as the rate increases the batch size naturally grows to whatever will keep up with the producer which means you don't have to decide what is the best batch size to use.

Comment: +1 I really like this approach. Hint: emphasize (for clarity) that `list` drains to a file.

Comment: There is one problem with this approach `drainTo` is not blocking so it will only process `available elements` if `maxElements` are not available. So it will not wait all threads to add up to `maxElements`

Comment: @AmitD That can also be seen as a feature. It could also be easily adapted to fill the list up to a threshold. Note that OP has the idea of a threshold only as an implementation convenience, which this approach has no need for.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes. It is just his idea. And with this approach there is no compulsion.

Comment: @AmitD Peter's solution can very easily be adapted to use a threshold---just put the `take();drainTo()` into a loop and substitute `maxElements-list.size()` for `maxElements-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Hold a reference to the message list in an `AtomicReference`.
2. When the list is full enough, replace it with a new, empty list;
3. pass the full list to a worker thread that will save the messages to a file.

If you write to the list from a single thread, it will be enough to use a plain reference instead of the `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the main message receiving process create a new message list once it has passed the old one to the file writing thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Custom `BoundedQueue` using [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) which accepts say `100` objects and then write at one go.

Now you can share this  `BoundedQueue` class instance with different threads which will put objects in it and there will be thread which will call `writeAll()` method until you want to call it.

```
BoundedBuffer boundedBuffer  = new BoundedBuffer();
boundedBuffer.put("test"); .......
```

From writing thread do below

```
boundedBuffer.writeAll();
```

Below is the sample code

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class BoundedBuffer {
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition full = lock.newCondition();
final Condition empty = lock.newCondition();

final Object[] items = new Object[100];
int count;

public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (count == items.length) {
            empty.signal();
            full.await();
        }
        items[count] = x;
        ++count;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void writeAll() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (count < items.length)
            empty.await();
        // Write to file here After write finished signal full condition
        count = 0;
        full.signal();

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
}
```